# Generate <div> section dynamically with a button in PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi guys I have a code that I want is inside a div and that I would like to generate 1 by 1 when the button 'Add Section' is clicked. Here's my code

surveycontent.php with javascript code

```
<div id="sform" class="tab-pane fade">

             <br>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-10" id="sections">
               <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Section 1</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


        <b>Number of Questions: </b>


                <span id="ctr_num"> <input id="q_num" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="q_num" size="2" placeholder="#"/></span>
                <br>


                 <b>Select Category</b>


                <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" id="categorydd" name="catdd" onChange="change_category()">

                    <option>-Please Select One-</option>

                    <?php
                    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoryname"]; ?></option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select><br>
            <b>Select Subcategory</b>

                <div id="subcategory">

                    <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">

                        <option>-Please Select One-</option>

                    </select><br/>

                </div>



        <p hidden>Select Questions</p>

         </br>

                <div id="question">



                </div>      <br/>





            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>



    <hr>



       <div class="col-md-2">
       <input type="submit" name="addsection" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Section" id="addsection" />

       </div>
</div>

    <script>
      function change_category()
        {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?category="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


            if(document.getElementById("categorydd").value=="Select")
            {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML="<select><option>Select</option></select>";
            }

            //alert(document.getElementById("categorydd").value);
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }


        function load_questions(){

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php??main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


        }
```

javascript code for add section button

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ctr = 0;
            $("#addsection").click(function(){
                 var section = document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML;
                $("#sections").append(section);


                ctr++;


            });

        });
    </script>
```

I assume this is wrong, because this code i have atm  will just make it bug like if I generate 1 section, and choose a data on the dropdowns for the added section, it will do the same thing to the first section, like it copies what you move for one section. This is a creation survey system and this is the part of adding sections.

The code behind those category, subcategory, question dropdowns.

ajax.php

```
if($category!=""){

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID =$category ");
    echo "<select id='subcategorydd' class='form-control' style='width:150px;' name='subcatdd' onchange='load_questions()' >";
    echo "<option selected>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[category_id]'>"; echo $row["categoryname"]; echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

// for loading ques under Category already
if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main == 1){
    $i = 0;
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++ ){
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT question.* FROM question LEFT JOIN category AS subcategory on subcategory.category_id = question.question_subcat WHERE question.question_category = $question AND (question.question_subcat IS NULL OR subcategory.category_id IS NOT NULL)");


        echo "<form>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$i}'>Question #{$i}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$i}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$i}'>
            <option selected>Select";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];
        }

        echo "
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id='txtHint{$i}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
    <br />";
    }
    echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>";

    echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues_Cat();'>Add Question</a> | ";
    echo "<a href='#del_question' onclick='return delQues();'>Delete Question</a>";
}

// for loading ques under SUBCATEGORY
if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main != 1){
    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++)
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_subcat = $question ");
        echo "
    <form>
        <b id='labelquestion_dropdown{$i}'>Question #{$i}</b>
        <select id='question_dropdown{$i}' class='form-control' onchange=\"showUser( this.value, 'txtHint{$i}' )\" style='width: 300px;' name='question_dropdowns{$i}'>
     <option selected>Select";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value='{$row['question_id']}'>" . $row["questiontitle"];
        }

        echo "
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id='txtHint{$i}'><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>  
    <br />";
    }

    echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>     ";

    echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues();'>Add Question</a> | ";
    echo "<a href='#del_question' onclick='return delQues();'>Delete Question</a>";
}
```

Comment: your code is messy., Clean it first.

Comment: What code do you want to put inside what div? Also, where is the 'Add section' button? The `</section>` just above 'Select Category' doesn't seem right either...

Comment: Can you specifie it little closer? 
What button you are presing?
Where is result suppose to display?
Where is result taken from?

Comment: Edited. Sorry sir @smzvax

Comment: Edited. Sorry sir @Meldon

Comment: Edited. Sorry sir @PavelHasala

Comment: I think the copying itself isn't the culprit per sé, although I'm sure there are better ways to add this kind of functionality (have a look at template engines, instead of copying HTML from the page - https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines). 

The fact that what happens in one section is applied to all sections probably has more to do with the JS that acts on the changes, i.e. `change_category()`. You probably target elements by id in that function and as you copied those HTML-elements they are in the document twice. id-attributes are supposed to be unique.

Comment: the HTML/php markup is invalid. There is a stray `</a>` tag towards the end with no opening tag and it looks like the div ( `id='sform'` ) is unclosed. I can see no element with id `addsection`

Comment: Hi sir @RamRaider we meet again!!! :)

Comment: Sir @RamRaider  the code you helped me back then with the categories and subcategories, that was the code behind those dropdowns I posted in my latest question. I added you in chat again if it's okay.

Comment: Sir @Meldon I just included the code and script behind the functions like change_category()

Comment: The markup is still invalid - there are 10 opening DIV tags but 12 closing. The `BR` tag should be `<br />` rather than `</br>` ( it is a self-closing tag, hence the slash is at the end )

Comment: I just removed some divs. How does it look now? @RamRaider

Comment: 11 closing div tags but 10 opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the HTML markup should perhaps be more like this. If you indent your code correctly as you go you will often find it is much easier to find issues.

There are several sites on the interwebs that could help with the code indentation - [for example](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html)  and you can validate your pages using other services, such as the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

```
<div id='sform' class='tab-pane fade'>
    <br />
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='col-md-10' id='sections'>
            <div class='panel-group'>
                <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>Section 1</div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <b>Number of Questions: </b>
                        <span id='ctr_num'> <input id='q_num' class='form-control' style='width:50px;' name='q_num' size='2' placeholder='#'/></span>
                        <br />
                        <b>Select Category</b>
                        <select class='form-control' style='width: 150px;' id='categorydd' name='catdd' onChange='change_category()'>
                            <option>-Please Select One-</option>
                            <?php
                                $query=mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT `category_id`, `categoryname` FROM `category` WHERE `ParentCategoryID` IS NULL');
                                while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
                            ?>
                            <option value='<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>'><?php echo $row['categoryname']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <b>Select Subcategory</b>
                        <div id='subcategory'>
                            <select class='form-control' style='width: 150px;'>
                                <option>-Please Select One-</option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <p hidden>Select Questions</p>
                        <br />
                        <div id='question'>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='col-md-2'>
    <input type='submit' name='addsection' class='btn btn-default' value='Add Section' id='addsection' />
</div>
```

I don't know if this will help or not or indeed whether I have understood the problem correctly ( that of effectively cloning the contents of the section when the button is clicked? )

The following clones the entire section ( there are no ID attributes to worry about but there will be duplicate names ) so a little more work would be invloved to make the new clone unique in the DOM and to change the section title / section number.

Copy and run the code - as posted - and see if it does more or less what you were trying to do. The ajax code does not perform all the tasks in the original code - like setting the contents of the `question`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* to emulate the ajax request that is sent by change_category() */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action']=='changecat' ){
            ob_clean();
            for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ )echo "<option value='$i'>Choice - $i";
            exit();
        }

    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cloning a section of the HTML page</title>
        <style></style>
        <script>
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    m=Method,
                    u=Url,
                    p=Params,
                    c=Callback,
                    o=Options
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
                        /*
                            The callback takes 3 arguments
                            ------------------------------
                            r=xhr.response
                            o=options ( as supplied to ajax function )
                            h=response headers
                        */
                        c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                    }
                };
                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }
                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }

            function change_category(evt){
                var el=evt.target;
                console.log('ajax function to get contents of dropdown - '+el.value+' & append returned data to subcategory?' );

                var method='post';

                var url=location.href;

                var params={
                    action:'changecat'
                };

                var callback=function(r,o,h){
                    var col=el.parentNode.querySelectorAll('select.subcategory');
                    if( col.length==1 )col[0].innerHTML=r;
                    col=el.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div.question');
                    if( col.length==1 )col[0].innerHTML='Some question - relating to Select:'+el.tagName+', Name:'+el.name+', Option:'+el.value+', chose from the database, goes here I believe?';
                }.bind( this );

                var options={};

                ajax.call( this, method, url, params, callback, options );
            }

            function clone_section(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var parent=document.getElementById('clone-parent');
                var col=parent.querySelectorAll('div.clone-section');
                var section=col[ col.length-1 ];
                var clone=section.cloneNode( true );

                /* change the heading */
                var heading=clone.querySelectorAll('div.panel-heading')[0];
                var regex=/(\d+)/gi;
                var matches=heading.innerHTML.match( regex );
                var i=parseInt( matches[0] );
                heading.innerHTML=heading.innerHTML.replace( i, i + 1 );

                /* make changes to the various cloned elements */
                var q_num=clone.querySelectorAll('input[name^="q_num_"]')[0];
                var matches=q_num.name.match( regex );
                var i=parseInt( matches[0] );
                q_num.name = q_num.name.replace(i,i+1);
                q_num.value='';

                var cat=clone.querySelectorAll('select[name^="catdd_"]')[0];
                var matches=cat.name.match( regex );
                var i=parseInt( matches[0] );
                cat.name=cat.name.replace(i,i+1);
                cat.value='';

                var subcat=clone.querySelectorAll('select[name^="subcategory_"]')[0];
                var matches=subcat.name.match( regex );
                var i=parseInt( matches[0] );
                subcat.name=subcat.name.replace(i,i+1);
                subcat.value='';

                parent.appendChild( clone );
            }

            function bindEvents(){
                var bttn=document.getElementById('addsection');
                    bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clone_section.bind( bttn ), false );
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',bindEvents,false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !isset( $_POST['action'] ) ){
                print_r( $_POST );
            }
        ?>
        <form name='geronimo' method='post'>

        <!--// markup from question //-->


        <div id='sform' class='tab-pane fade'>
            <br />
            <div class='col-md-12' id='clone-parent'>

                <!-- it is the following portion of HTML that is to be replicated? -->

                <div class='col-md-10 clone-section'><!-- removed ID, added new class -->
                    <div class='panel-group'>
                        <div class='panel panel-default'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>Section 1</div><!-- this needs to change progammatically or via CSS-->
                            <div class='panel-body'>
                                <b>Number of Questions: </b>
                                <span class='ctr_num'> <input class='form-control' style='width:50px;' name='q_num_1' size='2' placeholder='#' /></span>
                                <br />
                                <b>Select Category</b>
                                <select class='form-control' style='width: 150px;' name='catdd_1' onchange='change_category( event )'>

                                    <!-- PHP removed for example - replaced with dummy data -->

                                    <option>-Please Select One-
                                    <option value='a'>A
                                    <option value='b'>B
                                    <option value='c'>C
                                    <option value='d'>D
                                    <option value='e'>E
                                </select>
                                <br />
                                <b>Select Subcategory</b>
                                <div class='subcategory'>
                                    <select name='subcategory_1' class='form-control subcategory' style='width: 150px;'>
                                        <option>-Please Select One-</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                                <p>Select Questions</p>
                                <br />
                                <div class='question'></div><!-- assigned as a class rather than id - can be targeted using querySelectorAll etc -->
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- end replicated code -->

            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class='col-md-2'><!-- add new section button - uses javascript:onclick -->
            <input type='button' name='addsection' class='btn btn-default' value='Add Section' id='addsection' />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' /><!-- to actually submit the form -->

        <!--// end markup from question //-->

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this sir. My second problem is the appending part. I want to generate this code when the add section button is clicked. I done it but then it bugs when it gets to the question dropdown. Like if I choose a question from the second section, the first section that has loaded the question dropdown changes as well.

Comment: Your javascript code uses `$("#sections").append(section);` so as there can be only one instance of an ID that would seem to be the problem - no?

Comment: I think so. How to make it dynamic?or whats the right thing to do? @RamRaider